# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument error invoking get() with urls read from text file with Selenium Python

Tags: python, list, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of URLs in a .txt file that I would like to run using selenium.

Lets say that the file name is b.txt in it contains 2 urls (precisely formatted as below): 
https://www.google.com/,https://www.bing.com/,

What I am trying to do is to make selenium run both urls (from the .txt file), however it seems that every time the code reaches the "driver.get" line, the code fails.

```
url = open ('b.txt','r')
url_rpt = url.read().split(",")
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
for link in url_rpt:
   driver.get(link)
driver.quit()
```

The result that I get when I run the code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ASUS/PycharmProjects/XXXX/Test.py", line 22, in <module>
driver.get(link)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid 
argument
(Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

Any suggestion on how to re-write the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails?" Are you getting an exception? If so, what is the message and stacktrace? We need this basic info.

Comment: In the for loop above `driver.get(link)` add a line `print(link)`.

Comment: When "the code fails" what do you mean? What is the error message? What happens if you just run `for url in url_rpt: print(url)`. This might not be an issue with Selenium, but possibly with the `url` input and reading strategy. It would help to narrow down whether or not Selenium is truly throwing the error, or if the issue is with the file.

Comment: I'll update this on the post.

Comment: @Christine: Thanks! If I runa `for url in url_rpt: print (ur)` it would return both links just fine.

Comment: @Sakyamooni What happens if you just run `driver.get("https://www.google.com")`? Same error?

Comment: What happens when you comment out the calls to `options.add_argument`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .
    driver.get(link)
  .
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  .
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

...implies that the `url` passed as an argument to `get()` was an argument was invalid.

I was able to reproduce the same *Traceback* when the *text* file containing the list of urls contains a **space character** after the seperator of the last url. Possibly a *space character* was present at the fag end of *b.txt* as  `https://www.google.com/,https://www.bing.com/,`.

---

### Debugging

An ideal debugging approach would be to print the `url_rpt` which would have revealed the *space character* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  url = open ('url_list.txt','r')
  url_rpt = url.read().split(",")
  print(url_rpt)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.bing.com/', ' ']
  ```

---

### Solution

If you remove the **space character** from the end your own code would execute just perfecto:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
url = open ('url_list.txt','r')
url_rpt = url.read().split(",")
print(url_rpt)
for link in url_rpt:
   driver.get(link)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Realized that there is a comma at the end of the list! Thanks a lot for highlighting this!!

Comment: I encountered the same error when i forgot to start the url with `https://`

Comment: Same as @philomath I was getting that exception on driver.get() function and I solved it by using http:// as a prefix ( http:// localhost in my case)

Comment: I was adding a list using a multi line string inside a function, calling .splitlines() on it, and it was counting the indentation as a new array element with four spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a similar issue, where Selenium errored out while opening the URL and printed below message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=91.0.852.0)
```

On closely looking, i found that my url string was in 'UTF-8' and contained a leading ZWNBSP character, because of which selenium was not able to accept the URL(I was reading list of urls from a file, which caused this). IMO, selenium should have reported the error better(saying URL argument was invalid).

To rectify the issue, i used below code to clean my URL:

```
url = url.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: FYI, these extra characters(e.g. ZWNBSP ) might not be visible if we just print the URLs to check.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
link = 'https://' + link

driver.get(link)
```