# How to open and access multiple (nearly 50) tabs in Chrome using ChromeDriver and Selenium through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to gather some information from certain webpages using selenium and python.I have a working code for a single tab. But now i have a situation where i need to open 50 tabs in chrome at once and process each page data.

1) So open 50 tabs at once - The code i got already
**2) Change the control between tabs and process the information from the page and close the tab and move to next tab and do the same.**

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import psycopg2
import os
import datetime

final_results=[]
positions=[]
saerched_url=[]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("—-incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/user_123/downloads/chrome_driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

#def db_connect():
try:
     DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
     TABLE_NAME = 'staging.search_url'
     conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
     print("Database connected...")
     cur = conn.cursor()
     cur.execute("SET datestyle='German'")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
     print('database connection failed')
     quit()

def get_products(url):
    browser.get(url)
    names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pymv4e']")
    upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, names))
    product_name = [x.text for x in upd_product_name_list]
    product = [x for x in product_name if len(x.strip()) > 2]
    upd_product_name_list.clear()
    product_name.clear()
    return product


links = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=Vitamin+D',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=Vitamin+D3',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=Vitamin+D+K2',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=D3',
'https://www.google.com/search?q=Vitamin+D+1000']

for link in links:
    # optional: we can wait for the new tab to open by comparing window handles count before & after
    tabs_count_before = len(browser.window_handles)

    # open a link
    control_string = "window.open('{0}')".format(link)
    browser.execute_script(control_string)

    # optional: wait for windows count to increment to ensure new tab is opened
    WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(lambda browser: tabs_count_before != len(browser.window_handles))

    # get list of currently opened tabs
    tabs_list = browser.window_handles
    print(tabs_list)
    # switch control to newly opened tab (the last one in the list)
    last_tab_opened = tabs_list[len(tabs_list)-1]
    browser.switch_to_window(last_tab_opened)

    # now you can process data on the newly opened tab
    print(browser.title)


for lists in tabs_list:
    last_tab_opened = tabs_list[len(tabs_list)-1]
    browser.switch_to_window(last_tab_opened)
    filtered=[]
    filtered.clear()
    filtered = get_products(link)
    saerched_url.clear()
    if not filtered:
        new_url=link+'+kaufen'
        get_products(link) 
        print('Modified URL :'+link)

    if filtered:
        print(filtered)
        positions.clear()
        for x in range(1, len(filtered)+1):
            positions.append(str(x))
            saerched_url.append(link)

        gobal_position=0
        gobal_position=len(positions)
        print('global postion first: '+str(gobal_position))
        print("\n")

        company_name_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='LbUacb']")
        company = []
        company.clear()
        company = [x.text for x in company_name_list]
        print('Company Name:')
        print(company, '\n')


        price_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='e10twf T4OwTb']")
        price = []
        price.clear()
        price = [x.text for x in price_list]
        print('Price:')
        print(price)
        print("\n")

        urls=[]
        urls.clear()
        find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card']")
        for my_href in find_href:
            url_list=my_href.get_attribute("href")
            urls.append(url_list)

        print('Final Result: ')
        result = zip(positions,filtered, urls, company,price,saerched_url)
        final_results.clear()
        final_results.append(tuple(result))
        print(final_results)
        print("\n")


        print('global postion end :'+str(gobal_position))
        i=0
        try:
            for d in final_results:

                    while i <= gobal_position:
                      print( d[i])
                      cur.execute("""INSERT into staging.pla_crawler_results(position, product_name, url,company,price,searched_url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,%s)""", d[i])
                      print('Inserted succesfully')
                      conn.commit()
                      i=i+1
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
                 print (error)
                 pass


    browser.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you shouldn't attempt to *open 50 tabs at once* as:

- Handling 50 concurrent [TABs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230) through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) will invite complicated logic/algorithm to maintain.
- Additionally, you may run into [CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811) issues as:

  - *Chrome* maintains [many processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466).
  - Where as at times *Firefox* uses [too much RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072731/selenium-using-too-much-ram-with-firefox/55075243#55075243)

---

### Solution

If you are having a *List* of the urls as follows:

```
['https://selenium.dev/downloads/', 'https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/']
```

You can [iterate over the list to open them one by one in the adjacent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59755609/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-e/59761158#59761158) for scraping using the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  links = ['https://selenium.dev/downloads/', 'https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/']
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  for link in links:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
      driver.get(link)
      print(driver.title)
      print("Perform webscraping here")
      driver.quit()
  print("End of program")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Downloads
  Perform webscraping here
  The Selenium Browser Automation Project :: Documentation for Selenium
  Perform webscraping here
  End of program
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [WebScraping JavaScript-Rendered Content using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144599/webscraping-javascript-rendered-content-using-selenium-in-python/59156403#59156403)

Comment: @Sandeep Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Many thanks for this effort :) I have checked this code,this code open links in tabs and process it and close and opens a new chrome and open with new link and process it till end, But this is not the results what we want. We need to open 50 tabs at once and that is fine ,The issue is that after opening those 50 tabs it only process the last active tab and after the end when i gave "browser.close()" it is getting "NoSuchWindowException".

Comment: So i need a solution to resolve that, close the last active window.Move control to next process it and close it and move to next tab and do the same..Any suggestions on what i need to do to achieve it?

Comment: Try using multi-processing or multithreading.

Comment: @DebanjanB He was asking for simultaneously controlling all the tabs, which can be done only using the muti threaded or multiprocessing approach, while the answer focuses on a single tab approach which is irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan Did you go through the complete answer at least once? Didn't you find the rationale why I have suggested single tab against nearly 50 odd tabs? I think my suggestion was back by some solid reasoning. Your thoughts please...

Comment: I understand it, I believe it's better to let someone else answer it using the muti processing approach which solves the exact problem someone having instead of an answer which doesn't help at all. I am writing an answer shortly, it may help.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan Isn't _muti processing_ just another approach similar to single tab iterating over multiple tabs? In the question I don't even see _muti processing_ was a mandatory requirement.

Comment: Yes but it works simultaneously without any need to focus on any tab and switching.

Comment: So you mean to say _Selenium_ works even without focus on specific tabs? Strange enough !!!