# Selenium opens web browser but not the target url (InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried searching for the solution but nothing worked so this is my last hope. none of the other stackoverflow cases worked for me.

I try to run

```
from selenium import webdriver
b=webdriver.Chrome()

b.get("www.google.com")
```

but it only opens a `"data:,"` page with nothing.

In the terminal there is

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50361/devtools/browser/fef860a9-fd7b-4e53-9367-b7e59b57fa66
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Microsoft VS Code/CODES/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    b.get("www.google.com")
  File "C:\Users\istiak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\istiak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\istiak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

this. whats the best approach to this problem?
thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument error invoking get() with urls read from text file with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59755609/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.get()` parameter must be a valid formatted url and looking at the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException) you would get `InvalidArgumentException` when

> The arguments passed to a command are either invalid or malformed.

Try adding `http://` or `https://` to your `webdriver.get()`, as Selenium considers urls starting with `www...` as invalid:

```
b.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I feel very stupid right now... Thank you so much. i had sleepless night for this. :(