# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument while iterating through a list of urls and passing as argument to get()

Tags: python, list, selenium, get, invalidargumentexception

I am scraping a page to get the URLs and then use them to scrape a bunch of info. I'd like to avoid copying and pasting all the time but I cannot find how to make get() to work with the object. The first part of my code works perfectly well but when I get to the part that tries to get the url I get the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rcastong/Desktop/imgs/try-creating-object-url.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver4.get(urlworks2) 
  File "/Users/rcastong/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/rcastong/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/rcastong/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.109)
```

Here is part of the code

```
  #this part works well    
    for number, item in enumerate(imgs2, 1):
            # print('---', number, '---')
        
            img_url = item.get_attribute("href")
            if not img_url:
                print("none")
            else:
                print('"'+img_url+'",')
        
  # the error happens on driver4.get(urlworks2)        
        for i in range(0,30):
            urlworks = img_url[i]
            urlworks2 = urlworks.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')
            driver4 = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver4.get(urlworks2) 
            def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver3,55).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
                except TimeoutException:
                    return False
                return True
            
            imgsrc2 = WebDriverWait(driver3,55).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@data-testid='artistName']/ancestor::a[contains(@class,'ChildrenLink')]")))                                                                                                                 
            for number, item in enumerate(imgsrc2, 1):
                # print('---', number, '---')
                artisturls = item.get_attribute("href")
                if not artisturls:
                    print("none")
                else:
                    print('"'+artisturls+'",')
```

Comment: Hi @Remi try looking at this post it seems to be the same error 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59755609/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument-e

Comment: Thx @gedflod. I had seen this post but it is slightly different than my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .
    driver4.get(urlworks2) 
  .
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  .
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  .
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.109)
```

...implies that the `url` passed as an argument to `get()` was an argument was invalid.

---

### Deep Dive

With in the first `for` loop `item.get_attribute("href")` returns a url string and `img_url` gets updated at every iteration. So practically **img_url** remains a string but not a ***list of url*** as you assumed. As a result, in the second `for` loop when you try to iterate over the elements of a string and pass them to *`get()`* you see the error *`InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument`*.

---

### Demonstartion

As an example the below line of code:

```
img_url = 'https://www.google.com/'
for i in range(0,5):
    urlworks = img_url[i]
    urlworks2 = urlworks.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')
    print(urlworks2)
```

prints:

```
h
t
t
p
s
```

---

### Solution

Declare a empty list `img_url` within the global scope and keep on appending the *hrefs* to the list, so you can iterate the list later.

```
img_url = []
for number, item in enumerate(imgs2, 1):
    img_url.append(item.get_attribute("href"))
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument error invoking get() with urls read from text file with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761158/7429447)

Comment: Thx @undetected Selenium. That makes sense to me and I was suspecting something like that. I will give this a try.

Comment: Hi again, @undetected Selenium. You definitely put me on the right track so I marked your answer as accepted. The only thing I would add was slightly modify and insert with in the bigger loop: 
for i in range(0,30):
    img_url = []
    for number, item in enumerate(imgs2, 1):
        imgwors2 = item.get_attribute("href")

Not super familiar with stackoverflow's standards, should I post my entire modified code somewhere?

Comment: @RemiCastonguay Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: Hi again! No, what I meant is, thx to you I figured out how to make this work. Should I post my successful code somewhere?

Comment: @RemiCastonguay If the working (your) answer is entirely different from this answer, you should consider posting a new answer for the benefit of the future readers.